# Use Calibri for bold text and Calbri Light for everything else

Tags: fonts, fontspec

There are so many threads about using different fonts in many ways, but still not what I'm looking for. I need to use Calibri Light as my main font, but then I can not have anything in bold. Using Calibri (not Light) works, but then my normal text is not Light. How can I solve this? I might need to switch back and forth between the two and of course the best solution would be to just use `\textbf` with Calibri Light as the main font. Any suggestions?

Here is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Calibri Light}
\begin{document}
    This is normal text, while ... \\
    ... \textbf{this should be bold, but it is not!}
\end{document}
```

Oh, and I use `lualatex` since `pdflatex` cannot deal with Calibri.

Comment: I think you should revert your edit, the problem with the table is unrelated to the original question, you have simply used the wrong command, you want `\bfseries` to make all the text bold (just as you used `\color` not `\textcolor` to make it all red.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[BoldFont=Calibri]{Calibri Light}
\begin{document}
    This is normal text, while ... \\
    ... \textbf{this should be bold, but it is not!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple! Now I experience a similar behaviour within a `\table` environment. Edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I see, in that case I'll just accept and post another question.

Comment: @s6hebern I answered the table question in comments  above

Comment: Works smoothly, thanks!

Comment: What about `\textit` or `\emph`? They do not work as well.

Comment: specify ItalicFont=... just as you have BoldFont=... @s6hebern (does Calibri Light have a matching italic?)

Comment: I was doing it wroing... thought I needed to assign Calibri as italic font as well, but that then converts everything in `\textit` to normal Calibri font. Now that you named it, this works: `\setmainfont[BoldFont=Calibri, ItalicFont=CalibriLightItalic]{Calibri Light}`

Comment: @s6hebern yes I only used Calibri above as regular is "bold" if you start from light (by the way it is starting from light that means you have to do this, fontspec has quite good heuristics for finding the matching font names for different styles if you start from a "regular" font, but it can not handle this so you need to specify the style variants by hand)  sometimes this is needed anyway if the font designer has given more or less exotic names to the variants